# To prevent Memory Leaks, is it required to kill listeners which are placed inside a library too?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In an Android application,

To prevent Memory Leaks, is it required to kill listeners which are placed inside a library too?

For example,
There is an Image Listener for [CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview)

Is it required to take care of it's Image Listener and kill it on Activity Destroy of the activity which use it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, you should remove listeners when they are no longer needed. But because Android uses garbage collection, if there are no references to the object in the library that needed the listener, then when that object is culled the listener will be culled as well.

For example, I'm imagining that you create a new CarouselView object for each carousel you want to display. When the CarouselView is no longer needed, it will get removed, and then assuming that it didn't pass your listener anywhere else your listener will then get freed up as well.